# Rsync always do a copy from scratch with a mounted NAS

Tags: backup, rsync, synology, nas

I'm running this rsync command to back up a folder from my Mac to a mounted folder of my Synology NAS.

`rsync --no-compress -avAXEWSlHh --info=progress2 --delete-after /Volumes/SSD1TB/photos /Volumes/NAS/ssd-backup`

The thing is, every time I run this command, even if I didn't touch a thing in the folder, the copy takes the same time as the first copy I did:

```
sent 8.38G bytes  received 113.74K bytes  3.41M bytes/sec
total size is 8.37G  speedup is 1.00
```

No matter how many times I run the same command, on the same folder, the time is the same. Seems like in that case `rsync` is not useful at all, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Use `-i` to show why each file is being updated. Some filesystems dont keep timestamps in the same granularity, or convert timezones.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I'm getting `tp`, `t` or `p` on all the files... Any advice here ?

Comment: For time differences, most recommend `--modify-window=3602` to allow for a 1 hour difference +2 seconds to allow for a granularity of 2secs. You might be better off exporting from the synology using NFS, or enabling the rsync server on the synology (refer to "daemon" in the rsync man page). Also, try other sites as stackoverflow is more about programming.